# grep for multiple arguments, but output them in order of appearance

Tags: shell-script, command-line

I want to grep stuff out of an output file. For example `ab` and `cd`.

The file looks like:

```
asdf
ab
hgr
cd
ab
asdsda
```

if I now grep for `ab` and `cd` after one another like

```
for i in $@
do
  grep $i file
done
```

I get

```
ab
ab
cd
```

What I want though is

```
ab
cd
ab
```

Is there an elegant solution?

Comment: You can put the patterns in another file, then do something like `grep -F -f patterns file.txt`.  With GNU `grep` the `patterns` file can be `stdin`. Also consider investing two minutes in learning when and how to quote your variables, it will save you many an embarrassing posts to [unix.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get this result because loop first execute `grep ab file` and return all occurances of `ab` in first iteration and after this loop execute `grep cd file` and return all `cd` occurances in `file`.

You do not need a `for` loop. **Try this**:

```
grep -e "^ab$" -e "^cd$" file
```

Or use `-x` option to select only those matches that exactly match the whole line (from `man grep`, thx to [Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda)):

```
grep -x -e "ab" -e "cd" file
```

Output will be:

```
ab
cd
ab
```

**Or** (assuming GNU `grep` or compatible as `\|` is not a standard BRE operator):

```
grep "^\(ab\|cd\)$" file
```

The same with GNU `sed`:

```
sed '/^\(ab\|cd\)$/!d' file
```

Comment: Also see the `-x` flag for `grep`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, thx! I corrected the message in accordance with your recommendation

Comment: Note that `\|` is a GNU extension. Standardly, you can use `grep -xE 'ab|cd'`. In `sed`: `sed -e '/^ab$/b' -e '/^cd$/b' -e d`

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas, thx! I rolled back my answer to your edition and complete it with own comments

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
IFS='
' # to join "$*" with newline
grep -e "$*" < file
```

In `grep -- "$patterns"` or `grep -e "$patterns"`, each line of `$patterns` is a pattern to look for (ORed). (something you may need to bear in mind if any of the patterns in `"$@"` is itself multi-line)

In POSIX shells, `"$*"` is the concatenation of the positional parameters with the first character of `$IFS`.

Add the `-x` option if you want the patterns to match the lines e`x`actly (as opposed to substrings within the line).

Note that lines that match both `ab` and `cd` (so without `-x`) will be printed only once, which would be another difference from your multi-pass approach. If you wanted them to be printed once for each matching pattern, you'd use `awk` instead:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++) pattern[ARGV[i]]
    ARGC = 1
  }
  {for (p in pattern) if ($0 ~ p) print}' "$@" < file
```

Note however that `awk` patterns are extended regular expressions (like in `grep -E`) as opposed to the *basic* regular expressions understood by `grep` without `-E` (for instance, `x+` would match on `x+` with `grep`, but on one or more `x`es with `awk`).